# How to skip creating records with blank fields when migrating from csv file?

Tags: migrations, importing-exporting

I have created a migration with the **[Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate)** module that migrates data from a csv file into a custom entity. There are some rows in my csv file that don't have any data for the entity that I'm importing into, so I would like to skip the creation of those entities.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your prepareRow function test to see if a field is empty and if it is, return FALSE.  For example:

```
public function prepareRow($row) {
  if ($row->data == '') {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. It worked. Thank you. I'm so grateful this was so easy.